# SSIS: On successful write perform additional action

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about doing something that I am fairly certain that I should be able to do with SSIS.

I have two databases and I am updating Table B from Table A but as I do this I want to with ever successful write to Table B write some additional information to a log table back in the originating database. (See Illustration) 
[image]

I'm not sure what control(s) I would use to accomplish this but suspect that it can be done inside of SSIS.

Comment: You mean in a row by row insert operation?...I think that a trigger should be the best candidate for this kind of task instead of an ssis alternative...

Comment: You can do this also by regular t-sql: `begin tran -> write to tableB->write to log table->commit`. You may also create a **synonym** for "remote" table and write short direct references to it as if it was in current db.

Comment: @Hackerman - There are actually two separate operations that I will be building one will involve an insert of records while the other will be strictly updates of existing records. 
There are triggers already active in the table so adding more to it could be a problem. I would be best if we could accomplish this without manipulation of the database 2 content other than data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suggestions by Ivan Starostin and others on the board, I've opt'd to abandon using SSIS for doing this process and use stored procedures called from the code behind in the web page to perform this functionality. I'm including example of the insert process SP below as I'm working on the remainder but would like to close this question.  Thanks to Ivan and all for your input. SSIS simply wasn't the best tool for this situation. It was much cleaner using SP as I found out.

```
USE [CInTracDB]
GO

/******** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_InsertNewAssets]    Script Date: 12/15/2016 3:00:00 PM *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Ken Carter>
-- Create date: <Dec 15, 2016>
-- Description: <Input Fields from Updates table, Insert all NEW records into CMDB.dbo.cmdb_assets, then copy record from 
--               Updates to CInTracDB.dbo.Update_log, then Delete Record from Updates, 
--               Return only sucesss / fail signal.
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertNewAssets](
@CAssetID as  bigint,
@SubmitBy as varchar(50),
@SubmitDT as datetime,
@ApproveBy as varchar(50),
@Approved as char(10),
@ApprovedDT as datetime,
@Imported as char(10),
@ImportDT as datetime,
@AssetID as bigint,
@AssetType as int,
@AssetName as varchar(128),
@AssetShortDesc as varchar(50),
@AssetLongDesc as varchar(200),
@AssetAddNotes as varchar(254),
@AssetManuf as varchar(50),
@AssetModel as varchar(50),
@AssetTag as varchar(20),
@AssetAcqDate as datetime,
@AssetDTAssetID as varchar(20),
@AssetLocGrp as varchar(10),
@AssetLoc1 as varchar(8),
@AssetLoc2 as varchar(8),
@AssetLoc3 as varchar(8),
@AssetParent as bigint,
@AssetStatus as int,
@AssetPropType as int,
@AssetPrimUser as varchar(20),
@AssetEntered as datetime,
@AssetEnteredBy as varchar(50),
@AssetOwner as varchar(50),
@AssetCompany as varchar(10),
@AssetPriIPAddr as varchar(15),
@AssetPriMACAddr as varchar(17),
@AssetPriOS as varchar(20),
@AssetPriOSSP as varchar(20),
@AssetNotes as varchar(500),
@AssetAdminGrp as varchar(100),
@AssetSerialNum as varchar(75),
@AssetOperType as int,
@AssetOperStatus as int
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AssetFACL as bit = 0
DECLARE @AssetStatVer as bit = 0

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CMDB.dbo.cmdb_assets (AssetType, AssetName, AssetShortDesc, AssetLongDesc, AssetAddNotes, AssetManuf,
        AssetModel, AssetTag, AssetAcqDate, AssetDTAssetID, AssetLocGrp, AssetLoc1, AssetLoc2, AssetLoc3, AssetParent,
        AssetStatus, AssetPropType, AssetPrimUser, AssetEntered, AssetEnteredBy, AssetOwner, AssetCompany, AssetPriIPAddr,
        AssetPriMACAddr, AssetPriOS, AssetPriOSSP, AssetNotes, AssetAdminGrp, AssetSerialNum, AssetOperType, 
        AssetOperStatus, AssetFACL, AssetStatVer)

        SELECT AssetType, AssetName, AssetShortDesc, AssetLongDesc, AssetAddNotes, AssetManuf, AssetModel, AssetTag, 
        AssetAcqDate, AssetDTAssetID, AssetLocGrp, AssetLoc1, AssetLoc2, AssetLoc3, AssetParent, AssetStatus, AssetPropType, 
        AssetPrimUser, AssetEntered, AssetEnteredBy, AssetOwner, AssetCompany, AssetPriIPAddr, AssetPriMACAddr, AssetPriOS, 
        AssetPriOSSP, AssetNotes, AssetAdminGrp, AssetSerialNum, AssetOperType, AssetOperStatus
        FROM Updates
        WHERE AssetID > 0
END

BEGIN
    Insert INTO Update_log (CAssetID, SubmitBy, SubmitDT, ApproveBy, Approved, ApprovedDT, Imported, ImportDT, AssetID,
        AssetType, AssetName, AssetShortDesc, AssetLongDesc, AssetAddNotes, AssetManuf, AssetModel, AssetTag, AssetAcqDate, 
        AssetDTAssetID, AssetLocGrp, AssetLoc1, AssetLoc2, AssetLoc3, AssetParent, AssetStatus, AssetPropType, 
        AssetPrimUser, AssetEntered, AssetEnteredBy, AssetOwner, AssetCompany, AssetPriIPAddr, AssetPriMACAddr, AssetPriOS, 
        AssetPriOSSP, AssetNotes, AssetAdminGrp, AssetSerialNum, AssetOperType, AssetOperStatus)

        SELECT AssetType, AssetName, AssetShortDesc, AssetLongDesc, AssetAddNotes, AssetManuf, AssetModel, AssetTag, 
        AssetAcqDate, AssetDTAssetID, AssetLocGrp, AssetLoc1, AssetLoc2, AssetLoc3, AssetParent, AssetStatus, AssetPropType, 
        AssetPrimUser, AssetEntered, AssetEnteredBy, AssetOwner, AssetCompany, AssetPriIPAddr, AssetPriMACAddr, AssetPriOS, 
        AssetPriOSSP, AssetNotes, AssetAdminGrp, AssetSerialNum, AssetOperType, AssetOperStatus
        FROM Updates
        WHERE AssetID > 0
END

BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Updates
    WHERE (AssetID > 0)
END 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OLEDB Transformation to do the UPDATE to table B, and then follow that with a Destination that writes to the log table.

Comment: @Ivan_Starostin I'm leaning in the direction of your suggestion here and thinking of abandoning using SSIS altogether. I am considering writing two stored procedures and simply writing code to address that in my code behind page. I would give me the greatest amount of flexibility. I believe.

Comment: Using pure SQL is definitely the best way to go if the two databases are on the same server.   The only reason to use SSIS here is if the two are on different servers that cannot be linked.